# Installing an App from a different computer (with IDE) requires an App uninstall? How to prohibit the uninstall first?

Tags: android, eclipse

After installing an IDE on another computer, I tried to install an existing App on my mobile phone. During the deploy I was asked to uninstall the App first ... so losing all user settings in the App.

How can I work from a second computer (with Eclipse), install a new version of the App, without having to uninstall it (completely) first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the IDE creates a debug signing key for the debug app.

This signing key file changes location from system (Linux, Windows, Mac) or from IDEs (Android Studio, Eclipse).

The IDE ask for uninstalling if the signing key on the app installed on the device (phone) does not match the signing key on the computer.

So, to accomplish what you want, all you have to do is to copy the debug key from one computer to the other (so both will have the same key).

Just as a reference, using Ubuntu and AndroidStudio the debug key is at `~/.android/debug.keystore`

Comment: On windows ... I found the debug.keystore in Eclipse at: Windows > Preferences > Android > Build ... the location is shown in an edit box.